# JPList plugin only fires on first JQuery UI Tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jplist

I'm using the jQuery UI tabs to display 2 tabs. I have a single Bootstrap Dropdown Filter tied to the JPList Plugin. This should filter within each tab. The filtering works on the first tab, but not on the second tab.

To see what I mean, look at this [Fidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coryspi/jnvhxdx6/). If you run it, you will notice that you can select Air Conditioning and Filters to filter the items on the first tab. However, if you rerun it, and immediately click on the Flyers tab, neither filter will filter the items in that tab.

One thing I noticed is that it looks like my ".list" class should wrap all ".list-item" classes. I tried that and it blew up on me. Other than that, could it have something to do with the filter list changing after initialization?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="init">
        <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <ul role="tablist" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header">
                <li role="tab" tabindex="0" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#tabs-1" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-1">Promotions</a></li>
                <li role="tab" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-2" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2">Flyers</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#tabs-3">Social Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Articles</a></li>-->
            </ul>
            <!-- START Promotion Category Dropdown-->
            <div class="row catrow">
                <div class="jplist-panel">
                    <div class="dropdown text-center filter" data-control-type="boot-filter-drop-down" data-control-name="category-filter" data-control-action="filter" data-default="true">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdown-menu-1" aria-expanded="true">
                            <span data-type="selected-text">Filter by category</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-menu-1">
                            <li class="defaultItem" role="presentation" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" class="default" data-path="default" data-jplist-selected="true">Filter by category</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".AirConditioning" data-jplist-selected="false">Air Conditioning</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".Filters" data-jplist-selected="false">Filters</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".FlyerTestCategory1" data-jplist-selected="false">Flyer Test Category 1</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".FlyerTestCategory2" data-jplist-selected="false">Flyer Test Category 2</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".Heating" data-jplist-selected="false">Heating</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".Holidays" data-jplist-selected="false">Holidays</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".HVACRTips" data-jplist-selected="false">HVACR Tips</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".IAQ" data-jplist-selected="false">IAQ</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".LaborShortage" data-jplist-selected="false">Labor Shortage</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".NowHiring" data-jplist-selected="false">Now Hiring</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="filterMenu" style="display: none;"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-path=".Products" data-jplist-selected="false">Products</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /END Promotion Category Dropdown-->
            <!-- START Tab 1 -->
            <div id="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 header">Promotion Title</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 header">Download PDF</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Start List -->
                <div class="list">
                    <!-- Query for Promotion PDF files -->
                    <!-- START List Item -->

                    <!-- /END List Item -->
                    <!-- START List Item -->

                    <!-- /END List Item -->
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="promotions AirConditioning hide">Air Conditioning</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/IAQ-Allergies-Promo-Flyer-Template.pdf" target="_blank">
                            Promo 1                       </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/IAQ-Allergies-Promo-Flyer-Template.pdf" download="Promo 1">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="promotions Filters hide">Filters</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/IAQ-Allergies-Promo-Flyer-Template.pdf" target="_blank">
                            Promo 2                       </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/IAQ-Allergies-Promo-Flyer-Template.pdf" download="Promo 2">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /END List-->
            </div>
            <!-- /END Tab 1 -->
            <!-- START Tab 2 -->
            <div id="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" role="tabpanel" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 header">Flyer Title</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 header">Download Flyer</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Start List -->
                <div class="list">
                    <!-- Query for PDF files -->
                    <!-- Start List Item -->
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="flyers FlyerTestCategory1 hide">Flyer Test Category 1</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Honeywell-Lyric-Product-Bundle-Sell-Sheet-Template.pdf" target="_blank">
                            Honeywell Lyric Product Bundle Sell Sheet Template                        </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Honeywell-Lyric-Product-Bundle-Sell-Sheet-Template.pdf" download="Honeywell Lyric Product Bundle Sell Sheet Template">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /END List item -->
                    <!-- Start List Item -->
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="flyers FlyerTestCategory2 hide">Flyer Test Category 2</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/IAQ-Allergies-Promo-Flyer-Template.pdf" target="_blank">
                            Are You Ready For Allergy Season? IAQ Product Promo Template                          </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/IAQ-Allergies-Promo-Flyer-Template.pdf" download="Are You Ready For Allergy Season? IAQ Product Promo Template">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /END List item -->
                    <!-- Start List Item -->
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="flyers FlyerTestCategory2 hide">Flyer Test Category 2</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Humidifier-Winter-Graphic.pdf" target="_blank">
                            Why Get A Humidifier This Winter?                         </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Humidifier-Winter-Graphic.pdf" download="Why Get A Humidifier This Winter?">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /END List item -->
                    <!-- Start List Item -->
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="flyers FlyerTestCategory2 hide">Flyer Test Category 2</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Financing-Promo.png" target="_blank">
                            Financing Promo                       </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Financing-Promo.png" download="Financing Promo">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /END List item -->
                    <!-- Start List Item -->
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="flyers FlyerTestCategory1 hide">Flyer Test Category 1</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Laundry-Scrubber-Homeowner-Promo-Sheet-Template.pdf" target="_blank">
                            Laundry Scrubber Homeowner Promo Sheet Template                       </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Laundry-Scrubber-Homeowner-Promo-Sheet-Template.pdf" download="Laundry Scrubber Homeowner Promo Sheet Template">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /END List item -->
                    <!-- Start List Item -->
                    <div class="list-item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="flyers FlyerTestCategory1 hide">Flyer Test Category 1</span>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mt10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Air-Scrubber-Plus-Homeowner-Promo-Sheet-Template-1.pdf" target="_blank">
                            Air Scrubber Plus Homeowner Promo Sheet Template                          </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-center mb10">
                                    <a href="http://www.crescentparts.com/assets/Air-Scrubber-Plus-Homeowner-Promo-Sheet-Template-1.pdf" download="Air Scrubber Plus Homeowner Promo Sheet Template">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /END List item -->
                </div>
                <!-- /END List -->
            </div>
            <!-- /END Tab 2 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /END Init -->
    </div>
    <!-- /END Tabs -->
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    'use strict';

    // On Current Tab Click Run functions
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            activate: function(event, ui) {

                function getCategories(){

                //Show All Categories Before Running Filter
                var $filterMenu = jQuery('.filterMenu');
                $filterMenu.show();

                // Get current tab text
                var $tabText = jQuery(ui.newTab).text().toLowerCase();

                //Get list of categories found in current tab
                var catText = jQuery('.' + $tabText).map(function(i, cat) {
                    return jQuery(cat).text();
                }).get();

                // Create Array from Current Tab Categories
                var currCatTextList = catText.join(','),
                    currCatTextArray = currCatTextList.split(","),
                    currArray = currCatTextArray;

                // Log Current Tab Category Array
                console.log(currCatTextArray);

                //Hide li's in all category list not found in current tab
                jQuery('#tabs .dropdown-menu li').filter(function(idx, ele) {
                    return currArray.indexOf(ele.textContent) == -1;
                }).hide();
            }

            // Call getCategories Function on Tab Initialization and Each Tab Click
            getCategories();

            }
        })
        .tabs('option', 'active', 0)
        .tabs('option', 'collapsible', false);

         jQuery('#init').jplist({
                itemsBox: '.list'
                ,itemPath: '.list-item'
                ,panelPath: '.jplist-panel'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that one jplist instance can't have 2 ".list" sections.
One possible solution could be to transfer dropdown inside each tab and call a separate jplist instance in each tab.
The second option is to create a general ".list" wrapper around all tabs.